# Why does this code only work with tkinter and not CustomTkinter message box?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def msg_press_key():
    def on_press(key):
        print('{0} pressed'.format(key))
        return False

    messagebox.showinfo(title="Attention!", message="Press the button you want to register coordinates with")
    with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

the msg_press_key would be called whenever I press a button. The desired result would be me pressing said button, getting a message, and pressing any key that would then be printed to the terminal. the code above works just fine, but I would like to use the customtkinter message box instead

for some reason when I use

```
CTkMessagebox(title="Attention!", message="Press the button you want to register coordinates with")
```

I would not get the prompt until I pressed a key on my keyboard. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong... I'm new to python and I'm sorry for the noobish question but I've spent hours trying to find a solution to this.

Comment: Try calling `.update_idletasks()` on your root window (or any other widget) immediately after the call to `CTkMessagebox`.

Comment: that does work. Why is it doing this exactly?

Comment: Apparently CT's message box expects there to be a running event loop to handle events related to the box.  Calling `.update_idletasks()` will at least give the box a chance to draw itself (you'll probably find that it isn't actually functional at all, until a key has been pressed).

Comment: `messagebox.showinfo()` is a *modal* window, but `CTkMessagebox()` is not. You can call its `get()` function to make it a modal window: `CTkMessagebox(...).get()`